# how to animate two continuous popup windows with jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, popup

What I want to do with jquery mobile is when I click a button on the first popup window, the first popup window will disappear with a flip animation, after which the second popup window will appear with the same kind of animation. I tried to use this in the event listener:

```
$("#div_first").popup("close");
$("#div_second").popup("open");
```

The first popup window did disappeared. However the second popup window didn't popup. How can I do this with mobile jquery? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call next `popup` once the current popup is closed `popupafterclose`. Moreover, it is important to `data-history="false"` to popup div in order not to go back in history to previous activity.

```
$("#pop1").popup("open", {             /* open first popup */
    positionTo: "window",
    transition: "flip"
}).on("popupafterclose", function () { /* open second popup */
     $("#pop2").popup("open", {
       positionTo: "window",
       transition: "flip",
       reverse: true                   /* optional for reverse effect */
   });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/L5cNX/)**