# How to call a popup from a link inside another popup. Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, popup, jquery-mobile-popup

I have a `popup` like this:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popup1">
    <a href="#pop" data-rel="popup">Link to open popup</a>     
</div>
```

And the `div` for the `popup with id="pop"` is:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="pop">
    <!-- Content Here -->
</div>
```

So how do I `open the popup with id="popup"` from a link which is already inside a popup.

I tried the regular way. Did not work!

```
$("#popup1").popup('close');
$("#pop").popup('open');
```

Even the above did not work!

Comment: you have to close first one and then open the second one.

Comment: @Omar: Hi Omar! Wait a minutte i am trying it to close dynamically

Comment: `$("#button").on("click", function () { $("#pop1").popup("close"); $("#pop2").popup("open"); });` something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20811595/1771795

Comment: No tried the same. Did not work

Comment: See my question correctly again.

Comment: check the link in my previous answer. use `afterclose` event. a demo http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/yV6ME/

Comment: Nothing works. And also the popup on mobile devices does not function well. It is buggy. data-position = "window" does not work at all. Navigation just breaks if I use the back button. Over all this is the worst jquery mobile release ever. Just horrible in every way

Answer (score 0):

JQM Popups cannot be chained. You have to fire the second after a timer delay.

See the JQM documentation and search for "chain": http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/